# Listing users in Vue

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, vuejs3

```
<script setup>
import { getDatabase, ref as dbref, query, get, child, orderByChild, startAt, endAt, onValue } from "firebase/database";
import { reactive, ref } from "vue";

const db = getDatabase();

const dbRef = dbref(db, '/users');
const data = ref()

onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    const childKey = childSnapshot.child('username').val();
    const childData = childSnapshot.val();
    data.value = childKey
    // ...
  });
}, {
  onlyOnce: true
});
const test = ref( data )
</script>

<template>
<div v-for="item in test">
{{ test }}
</div>
</template>
```

The list looks like that:

```
Alexander
Alexander
Alexander
Alexander
Alexander
Alexander
Alexander
Alexander
Alexander
```

What can i do to list all users, not only one? I tried different things and nothing works. The only thing that works is, using Pinia, but then, how again, can i filter the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start using `data` as an empty array, then fill it after onValue event. Use push to this array instead of assignment:

```js
<script setup>
import { getDatabase, ref as dbref, query, get, child, orderByChild, startAt, endAt, onValue } from "firebase/database";
import { reactive, ref } from "vue";

const db = getDatabase();

const dbRef = dbref(db, '/users');
const data = ref([]);

onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    const childKey = childSnapshot.child('username').val();
    const childData = childSnapshot.val();
    data.value.push(childKey); 
    // ...
  });
}, {
  onlyOnce: true
});
</script>

<template>
<div v-for="user in data">
{{ user }}
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Push method is great, but it is great only for lists that are resembling stats, and don't link to the profile of the user. Because there has to be state management to carry the computed route over multiple components, for which it needs something likesuch as Pinia. Because Vue forgets the computed state needed to trespass the component structure. Does someone know how to filter the objects in Pinia with v-for="user in users"? Because the slice does not work there with Pinia. They should develop a myst method.